# How do I make a product that is configurable and downloadable?

Tags: magento-enterprise, configurable-product, downloadable

I have a set of downloadable products that need to be put together in a configurable product.  It all seems to work fine, except that the parent product isn't allowed to have a downloadable item assigned to it.

Is there a way to add a download file to a configurable parent product?

Or alternatively, is there a way to only allow users to purchase the child products, and not the parent product?

Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Depending on your catalog size, you could create a category as the parent and add downloadable products to it.  It's not going to be as elegant though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to be able to add a downloadable product to configurable product, you can create a simple module with the following markup in your `config.xml`:

```
...
<global>
    <catalog>
        <product>
            <type>
                <configurable>
                    <allow_product_types>
                        <downloadable/>
                    </allow_product_types>
                </configurable>
            </type>
        </product>
    </catalog>
</global>
```

Comment: awasome answer...upvote from me

Comment: @AmitBera Thank you! I highly appreciate that. I have used this before with bundle products so I assume that it will work for configurables as well.

Comment: Didn't seem to change anything for me. Maybe I did it wrong?  I've got the config.xml file created, I've got the etc/modules xml file created.  It shows up in the admin under configuration/advanced as "enabled".  But everything seems the same.  What should change, exactly?

Comment: You should be able to add downloadable products as child products of configurable products now.

Comment: Not sure why it didn't work before, but it is working now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Step1: `create custom module with a table .`

Step2:`table is containing with field SKU and save file upload path.,file nam`e.

Step3: `create a section at admin from where you upload file using varien file uploaded.. Respect to configurable product sku`

Step4: `after order place give a link to download  files respect with order item..`